# Misplaced comma after LTR word in bidirectional document

Tags: punctuation, hebrew, right-to-left

I am writing documents with both English and Hebrew text in LaTeX. It works well, except for one thing: when there is a punctuation mark after an English word in a Hebrew sentence, the mark is misplaced.

Here is a small reproducible example, a file named `test.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}
\let\hebrewfonttt\ttfamily
\begin{document}
המסמך הזה כתוב עם LaTeX, ומשלב בין עברית לאנגלית.
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\setLTR

This document is written with LaTeX, and combines Hebrew and English.

\unsetLTR
\end{document}
```

which I process with:

```sh
xelatex test.tex
```

and get the following result:

[image]

In the first (Hebrew) sentence, the comma is misplaced. In the Hebrew sentence, the comma should be to the *left* of the word LaTeX, because the Hebrew text is RTL.

The correct arrangement can be seen in a text editor, such as gedit:

[image]

I'm not experienced with LaTeX, and couldn't find a solution online. Will appreciate any help with this, thank you very much!

Comment: If the compiler takes the "LaTeX," bit literally (without moving the comma) can't you just put it into the text as ",LaTeX" ? Or is this a reoccurring fault that needs sorting?

Comment: You mean placing the comma in the "wrong" side of the word, right? Didn't think of it, just tried and it works! Thanks! Could be great if there is any more standard solution, but if there isn't this is what I'll do

Comment: `LaTeX\/,` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! This works fine in the independent `tex` file example above, but doesn't work in RMarkdown (where I eventually need to prepare the text)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XeTeX and/or the bidi package seems not to handle this correctly. With lualatex and babel it works out of the box (I don't have your font here, so use another one):

```
% compile with lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{Libertinus Serif} % 
\begin{document}
המסמך הזה כתוב עם LaTeX, ומשלב בין עברית לאנגלית.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The example you kindly gave works well. However, I need the document to contain LTR as well... When trying to add the `\setLTR This document is written with LaTeX, and combines Hebrew and English. \unsetLTR` part, I get an error that `\setLTR` is an undefined control sequence...

Comment: sure it iuses babel and not the bidi package. Use \selectlanguage{english} and check the babel documentation.

Comment: I will check it out, marking as solved - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using LuaTeX for bidirectional typesetting, as Ulrike suggested, if possible.  This answer is just in case someone wants to use XeTeX.

Just to show this is a problem in the engine itself, you can check the result of the following code

```
\font\david="David CLM Medium/OT:script=hebr,mapping=tex-text;"\david
\TeXXeTstate=1\beginR
    המסמך הזה כתוב עם LaTeX, ומשלב בין עברית לאנגלית.
\bye
```

[image]

You can make XeTeX apply the BiDi algorithm to bigger chunks of text by setting `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping` to a bigger number, but it can have other side effects as well.

```
\font\david="David CLM Medium/OT:script=hebr,mapping=tex-text;"\david
\TeXXeTstate=1\beginR
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping=2
    המסמך הזה כתוב עם LaTeX, ומשלב בין עברית לאנגלית.
\bye
```

[image]

or with XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}[Script=Hebrew]
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping=2
\begin{document}
    המסמך הזה כתוב עם LaTeX, ומשלב בין עברית לאנגלית.
\end{document}
```