# How to get a system font which works with xelatex to work with lualatex?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, hebrew

I'm trying to convert a document from using xelatex+polyglossia to luatex+babel (following a suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598581/5640)).

The relevant code is:

```
\usepackage[english, bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont[*hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
```

lualatex starts to chug along, but then says:

```
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "Font DavidCLM not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "DavidCLM" cannot be found.
```

David CLM is a system font (on my Devuan GNU/Linux 3.0 Beowulf system); and xelatex is able to use it. Why can't lualatex also use it? And how can I make lualatex recongize and use the font?

Comment: you could try the font file name rather than name (although usually luatex can find fonts by name) what is the actual path to the font ?

Comment: You have to explicitly specify which font should be used for regular weight and which one for bold. The autodetection fails since there is no regular version of the font.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: See my answer. But please consider adding your own with an example of when this would work and when it would fail.

Answer (score 2):

If XeTeX can find the font, `fc-match` should as well.  So, you can get all the names it’s indexed under with

```
fc-match -v "David CLM"
```

On my system, this tells me that the filename is `DavidCLM-Medium.otf`, the family is "David CLM", the style is "Medium" and the fullname is "David CLM Medium".  XeTeX is matching "David CLM" with "David CLM Medium", and LuaTeX is not.

The recommended way to load the font family is by its filenames:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures = TeX }

\defaultfontfeatures[DavidCLM]{
  UprightFont = *-Medium,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  Ligatures = Discretionary,
  Extension = .otf,
  % For italics that slant right-to-left, use:
  ItalicFont = *-MediumItalic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  % For italics that slant left-to-right, instead use:
  % AutoFakeSlant = 0.15
  }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          {David CLM}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
שָׁלוֹם חֲבֵרִים
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image: David CLM sample]

This removes all guesswork and tells `fontspec` to look for files with the exact names `DavidCLM-Medium.otf`, `DavidCLM-Bold.otf`, etc.

A more minimal MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[import, main]{hebrew}

\babelfont{rm}
          [UprightFont=*-Medium]{DavidCLM}

\begin{document}
שָׁלוֹם חֲבֵרִים
\end{document}
```

[image: David CLM sample]

Note that I have [version 1.33 of the Culmus Project fonts installed.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/culmus/files/culmus/0.133/)  If you have a different version installed on your system, your files might have different filenames.  You should also be able to load it by family name plus style, as `UprightFont = {David CLM Medium}, BoldFont = {David CLM Bold}` (not worrying about slanted faces you don’t want).

Comment: How much of the code is necessary for the import, and how much is just code from wherever you copied this? For example, does the command with TeX Gyre Schola matter for Hebrew at all? How about the font features (scale, ligatures)? I'm guessing they don't really apply to Hebrew fonts. etc.

Comment: Also - it is a faux pas, typography-wise, to use "italic" Hebrew fonts. There is no such thing, historically and culturally. It's just a meaningless, and regrettable, attempt to copy a kind of variant which exists in Latin-alphabet languages. Silly insistence on "Italic has to do something in Hebrew too" by word processor makers (*cough* Microsoft *cough*) has made this abomination popular among lay authors, but no professionally-typed document has that.

Comment: @einpoklum I didn’t copy it from anywhere. You don’t need Schola; I just gave it as an example of using different fonts for English and Hebrew. You do need just about everything else.

Comment: @einpoklum You can call it `SlantedFont=` and `BoldSlanted=` font instead if you want. You could also load Drugulin as your alternative typeface instead, which is a bit more traditional. In that case, you’d load the font family with `\newfontfamily\drugulin` and then something like `\declaretextfontcommand\textemhe{\drugulin}`.

Comment: I think the minimal version is, `\babelfont{rm}[UprightFont=*-Medium]{DavidClM}`.

Comment: Minimum version doesn't work either, I get: `Package fontspec Error: The font "UprightFont=*-Medium" cannot be found.`

Comment: @einpoklum It works fine for me. I’ll add the two lines to expand it to a MWE.

Comment: @einpoklum You might have an older version of the font package installed. If so, `[UprightFont = {David CLM Medium}, BoldFont = {David CLM Bold}]` should work for you, as you do not want slanted Hebrew.

Comment: I have the culumus 0.133-1 package on Devuan (~= Debian) stable. Also, using "David CLM Medium" doesn't work either. And again - I can't use `\defaultfontfamily` , so I tried with the "minimal version".

Comment: @einpoklum My code snippet had an error. That should have been `\defaultfontfeatures`. My mistake. There is no `\defaultfontfamily`. I replaced it by a MWE that definitely works.

Comment: @einpoklum What does the command at the top of my answer, `fc-match -v "David CLM"`, tell you are its ``family``, `style`, `fullname` and `file`?

Comment: `family: "David CLM"(s)  style: "Medium"(s)  fullname: "David CLM Medium"(s)  file: "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/culmus/DavidCLM-Medium.otf"(w)`

Comment: @einpoklum Then what I posted ought to be working. What does `luaotfload-tool --find "David CLM Medium"` give you? Does `luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v` correctly add it to the index?

Comment: Can `luaotfload-tool --list=fullname:"David CLM*"` find it? What about `luaotfload-tool --list=fontname:"DavidCLM*"`>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a smarter solution, but here's what I did. Answers to this question:

[How do I get a list of all available fonts for luaotfload?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14162/5640)

allow you to list all fonts you can use with lualatex (for some definition of "use"). I looked for the basic part of my font's name, "David", but while ignoring capitalization, because all items on the list seemed to be lower caps. So:

```
$ ./listluatexfonts | egrep -i "david.*clm" | sort -u
davidclmbold
davidclmbolditalic
davidclmmedium
davidclmmediumitalic
taameydavidclmbold
taameydavidclmboldoblique
taameydavidclmmedium
```

and the bottom line answer for my case is `davidclmmedium` for my `{rm}` font. Maybe I also need to issue commands for bold.

---

For completeness, the `listluatexfonts` file's contents are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

kpse.set_program_name("listluatexfonts")
cachefile  = kpse.expand_var("$TEXMFVAR")  .. "/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc"
fontlist = dofile(cachefile)
assert(fontlist,"Could not load font name database")

local tmp = {}

for _,font in ipairs(fontlist.mappings) do
  tmp[#tmp + 1] = font.fontname
end
table.sort(tmp)

for _,fontname in ipairs(tmp) do
  print(fontname)
end
```

Comment: You can do the same query with `luaotfload-tool --list=fontname:"*David*CLM*"`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: I can run that, but it doesn't produce any results for some reason.

Comment: Is your TeX Live version up-to-date?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: Nope, it's TeXLive 2019. I'm on Devuan 3 (~= Debian Stable).

Comment: That explains the issue. Wildcard support was added in v3.13, but TeX Live 2019 got frozen at v3.12.

Comment: So the more precise comment is: Starting with TeXLive 2020, you can do the same query with `luaotfload-tool --list=fontname:"*David*CLM*"`.